# Filter array and print to HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JS and am currently learning about Arrays.

I'm stuck as how to print out the `description` property of the array for the filtered item, all I'd like to show is "item 1" however currently I'm getting `[Object object]`.

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    description: "item 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "item 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "item 3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    description: "item 4"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    description: "item 5"
  }
]

let filterArray = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.description === 'item 1'
})

let filterOutput = document.createElement('p');
filterOutput.innerHTML = filterArray
document.querySelector('#filtered').appendChild(filterOutput);
```

```html
<div id="filtered"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `filterOutput.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filterArray.map(x => x.description))` if you want to show just the description.

Comment: Note that you could also `.find` the wanted element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filterArray` looks like this `[{id: 1, description: "item 1"}]`, which is an Object. JavaScript can't create Strings from Objects per se (it will just turn out to be `[Object object]`), what you probably want is 
    `filterArray[0].description`

Answer (score 0):

You have to stringify your data.

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    description: "item 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "item 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "item 3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    description: "item 4"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    description: "item 5"
  }
]

let filterArray = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.description === 'item 1'
})

let filterOutput = document.createElement('p');
filterOutput.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filterArray)
document.querySelector('#filtered').appendChild(filterOutput);
```

```html
<div id="filtered"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you're trying to set a string from an Object and JS is unable to.

Here are the steps to reach the desired solution. Your filter is going to return a list, since only one of your elements is going to match the filter (as it's done by `id`), you first need to access the position `[0]`. Then, get the `description` property. As you only want "item 1" to be printed, use this:

```
let filterOutput = document.createElement('p');
filterOutput.innerHTML = filterArray[0].description
document.querySelector('#filtered').appendChild(filterOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so why do you get this error? Because :
The default conversion from an object to string is "[object Object]".

This means you're trying to set the value of 'filterOutput' to be an object.
This happens here

```
filterOutput.innerHTML = filterArray
```

If you console.log filterArray you will notice it's an array with one element.
So let's get this one element.

```
let filterArray = items.filter(function (item) {
  return item.description === 'item 1'
})[0]
```

Notice how we added `[0]` to the end of your expression. This is so we can get the first element of the filtered elements.

If now you console log the result of filterArray you'll see it's an object.
The problem persists. But you said you want to display "Item 1". This means you want to display the 'description' property of the object. Let's do that.

```
filterOutput.innerHTML = filterArray.description
```

Also, you should check out

> [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

and why it's better than filter in your case for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Because `filter` will return array you should access found item by `index` like `filterArray[0].description` if you want completely print found item you can use `JSON.stringify` like the mentioned before.
totally `filter` runs till the end of the array because of this it will return array, and invokes its callback on every item; in contrast to find which stops after having found one because this `find` will return one item.
so you can use `find` instead of `filter` and access that property like `filterArray.description` or do :

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    description: "item 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "item 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "item 3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    description: "item 4"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    description: "item 5"
  }
]

let filterArray = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.description === 'item 1'
});

let filterOutput = document.createElement('p');
filterOutput.innerHTML = filterArray[0].description;
document.querySelector('#filtered').appendChild(filterOutput);
```

```html
<div id="filtered"></div>
```

if you want to return `description` directly you have to use `map` of filter to return what you want like:

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    description: "item 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "item 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "item 3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    description: "item 4"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    description: "item 5"
  }
]

let filterArray = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.description === 'item 1'
})
.map(function(item) {
  return item.description;
});
let filterOutput = document.createElement('p');
filterOutput.innerHTML = filterArray;
document.querySelector('#filtered').appendChild(filterOutput);
```

```html
<div id="filtered"></div>
```